# Using JavaScript Client OM gives error "ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded was not defined"

Tags: client-object-model

I have:

IN THE HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <title>Buscador</title>
    <script src="lib/jquery-1.4.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="buscador.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <script src="lib/jquery.autolink.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   
</head>
<body       
    <h1>Buscador</h1>
        Esta es la prueba de poner tooltip a una no mas Prueba para ver
        El elemento solo tiene que tener el atributo title="mensaje del tooltip" y 
</body>
</html>
```

And in the javascript:

```
function getList(){
    //_listDiccionario = Array(new Array("elemento","Este es el mensaje"), new Array("mensaje","cosas rarascosas ")); //Para probar

    /* Retrieves the current ClientContext object */
     //var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    var webUrl = "http://c-jfmunoz:5000";  
    var context = new ClientContext(webUrl); 

    var web = context.get_web();

    // Get references to the lists we will use
    var listObject = web.get_lists().getByTitle(_listName);

    // Get the list items for the contacts list 
    _listDiccionario = listObject.getItems();

    // context.load tells the object model to load the objects scalar 
    // properties. Otherwise they will not be accessible 
    context.load(_listDiccionario);
    context.load(listObject);
    context.executeQueryAsync(onListsLoaded);
}

/* 
    Event handler called loading the contacts and companies lists
    This method dynamically renders an HTML table to display the list data 
*/

function onListsLoaded() {
    addToolTipToList("body","0000FF",_listDiccionario);
    return false;
}
```

And when I run it it says "ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded was not defined"

I think that nothing will work.
Is there anything that I must add to the JavaScript file to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Have you included any of the SharePoint javascript code in your page? ie: script refs to sp.js?

Also, where is your HTML page running from? I'm not sure if it works outside the context of a SharePoint site.

If you need a hand getting started with the JavaScript Client Object Model, have a read through this tutorial:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/60348/SharePoint-2010-Client-Object-Model-for-JavaScript.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Now it's working :)

The problem now is that I have a list called 'Lista Diccionario'
and I want to get all the items there.

"There's the code" but it doesn't work.

look:

```
var _listName = "Lista Diccionario";
var _listDiccionario;

$(document).ready(function() 
{
    //_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("Initialize()");
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(initialize, "sp.js");  
    //getList();
    //addToolTipToList("body","0000FF",_listDiccionario);
});

function initialize(){
    getList();
}

function addToolTipToList(where, color, list){
    for( i=0 ; i < list.length ; i++){
        addTooltipToText("body", "0000FF", list[i][0], list[i][1]);
    }
}

function addTooltipToText(where, color, text, tooltipMessage) {
   $(where).replaceEachOne(text, '<label style="color:#'+ color + ';" title="' + tooltipMessage + '">$1</label>');
}

//Ejemplo en http://sharepointbloggin.com/2010/02/10/walkthrough-4-accessing-list-data-using-the-javascript-client-om/
    function getList(){
        //_listDiccionario = Array(new Array("elemento","Este es el mensaje"), new Array("mensaje","cosas rarascosas ")); //Para probar

        var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        this.web = ctx.get_web();
        ctx.load(this.web);

        /*var webUrl = "http://c-jfmunoz:5000";  
        var context = new ClientContext(webUrl); */

        // Get references to the lists we will use
        var listObject = web.get_lists().getByTitle(_listName);

        ctx.load(listObject);

        // Get the list items for the list 
        _listDiccionario = listObject.getItems();

        // context.load tells the object model to load the objects scalar 
            // properties. Otherwise they will not be accessible 
            ctx.load(_listDiccionario);

            ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onListsLoaded),
                                    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onListsFailed));
        }

    /* 
        Event handler called loading the contacts and companies lists
        This method dynamically renders an HTML table to display the list data 
    */
    function onListsLoaded(sender, arg) {
        addToolTipToList("body","0000FF",_listDiccionario);
        return false;
    }

    function onListsFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('failed to update title. Error:'+args.get_message());
        return false;
    }
```

UPDATE:

I change the name of the list from "Lista Diccionario" to "Diccionario" and now it works!!!

Comment: It goes to the onListsFailed method,
Where's the error?