# Jquery and csom problem

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jsom

Hi im having some code like this:

```
var News = new Array();

jQuery(document).ready(function () {

 ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(initialize, "sp.js");  

 some code here...

 function setUpList(){
 }

 }
 });

 function initialize(){

 im retrieving my list items and store them in my global array News

 then im calling the function setUpList(); in jquery document ready..

 }
```

But its not working to call the function setUpList, its says its undefined, how can i work this out?

Becouse i need to use both jquery and get the list with csom

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to call the function setUpList, which is defined within the ready function callback, from the initialize function which is outside the ready callback scope, and that's why you are getting undefined.

Just move your setUpList function outside, at the same level of the initialize function.
Something like:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(initialize, "sp.js");  

function initialize(){
   jQuery(document).ready(function () { //something here  });
}

function setUpList(){}
```

If you are worried about cluttering the global namespace, you can put all your functions inside a global object that you'll use as a namespace.

Eg:

```
var MyLib = {}; // global Object cointainer
MyLib.initialize = function(){};
MyLib.setUpList = function(){};

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(MyLib.initialize, "sp.js");
```

Comment: okey, and it will load the list items and all that

Comment: @Jarule is that a question?

Comment: function intitalize have some csom code to retrieve list items, and it wont work to retrieve list items if its in the jquery document ready

Comment: You didn't show us the full code. Adjust my snippet to suite your needs

Comment: yes the code is to long, 10 pages

Comment: After i have called the intitalize function, i must call the functions inside Jquery document ready, and its not working

Comment: sorry, without seeing the code I can't really help. What I can suggest is that you make sure you understand javascript scoping, before diving too deep in writing code

Comment: I understand javascript scope, but i dont understand how to load a list when the DOM is loading

Answer (score 1):

shouldnt the function be outside of the function?

```
var News = new Array();

jQuery(document).ready(function () {

 ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(initialize, "sp.js");  

 some code here...

 now call my function!!!!
 setUpList();
 });

 function setUpList(){
 }

 }

 function initialize(){

 }
```

you cant call a function that is within the same function! as you have created a function `setUpList` within the main function it cant find it as functions reside outside of each other! in your case it could only see `initialize` function and it threw that exception!

Comment: That dont work, it wont load my list items...

Comment: are you loading the items in the initialize method? have a look here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/8602/using-javascript-client-om-gives-error-executeordelayuntilscriptloaded-was-not

Comment: If i load it before the jquery document ready , then i cant call the function inside jquery document ready from intitialize method

Comment: and if i have the initialize code inside jquery document ready then its not loading the list..